# Is there any way to fit a model for graph analysis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, model, curve-fitting

[image: Model_fit_MATLAB_Fig1]

I am getting the plot as shown in the figure in MATLAB after applying some function. On fitting a polynomial, we see that we get a parabolic curve for this curve as shown in the next figure. [image: Model_fit_MATLAB_Fig2]. Is there any way that I can develop some model that can tell that this graph is a parabolic graph. Or from the values from which this curve is generated, is it possible to comment for the same?

Edit:
Here is my code:

```
`
clear
tab=csvread('test_cs22.csv',1,0);
x=tab(:,1); 
y=tab(:,2); 
p=polyfit(x,y,2); 
pp=polyval(p,x); 
plot(x,y) 
hold on 
plot(x,pp,'-r');`
```

I am taking in the input from a csv file that consists of data in this manner.

1 89420
2 64614
3 60377
4 105717
5 111244
6 151984
7 108780
8 273562
9 182516
10 221625

Comment: Are you asking how to tell what structured model best fits your data? It really depends on what options you are going to allow but probably the easiest is to do the regression on a few different models (say, polynominal orders 1 to 3, exponential and log) and then compare their R² values. Did you use `fitlm` to find your orange curve? You should provide the code...

Comment: @Dan Sorry.. I didn't get you. How regression can be done on this data?  Can you kindly elaborate more. 
Anyway here is my code.

clear
tab=csvread('test_cs22.csv',1,0);
x=tab(:,1);
y=tab(:,2);
 p=polyfit(x,y,2);
 pp=polyval(p,x);
 plot(x,y)
 hold on
 plot(x,pp,'-r');

I am taking in the input from a csv file that consists of data in this manner.
1 89420
2 64614
3 60377
4 105717
5 111244
6 151984
7 108780
8 273562
9 182516
10 221625

Comment: (a) edit your question to add your code there, it's too difficult to read in the comments, (b) regression is exactly what `polyfit` does

Comment: @Dan edited my question.

Comment: So what I was suggesting is that you need to check the R² value to determine how good your fit is. `polyfit` doesn't give your the R² by itself so I would suggest rather using [`fitlm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html#bt0clc5-1). You should fit multiple models such as polynomials with orders `1` to `n` (you choose `n`) and then also fit exponential (you'll need to make a log-linear transformation) and logarithmic just to cover your bases. This is to answer your second question of how to tell from the raw values what structure your model should have.

Comment: Your first question seems to ask how you can know that the orange curve you generated using `polyfit`/`polyval` is quadratic? Well it is by definition since you specified that `polyfit` fit a polynomial model with degree `2` (i.e. a quadratic). That's what the `2` in `p=polyfit(x,y,2);` did.